# "sh" - URL validation

Tags: shell, validation, url, sh

Can some one help me to perform the URL validation for the SH shell (not bash) ?

Tried the following one.. and seems to be not working fine.

```
regex='(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%=~_|]'
string=$1
if echo "$1"|grep -q '$regex';then
    echo "Link valid"
else
    echo "Link not valid"
fi
```

Comment: There's no "sh" shell -- there's bash in compatibility mode, which nowadays is used most of the time. Point is that you can't rely on bash's advanced features in something that is called /bin/sh (which, by the way, on my system is but a symlink to /bin/bash).

Comment: Also, "not working fine" is not describing your problem *at all*. At least try to explain what works, what fails, if you have tried to test parts of your regex...

Comment: On the Linux versions based on Debian (Ubuntu amongst others) `/bin/sh` is a symlink to [`dash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell).

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ "There's no 'sh' shell" is not necessarily true. "sh" is the traditional name for the Bourne shell (that's why there's a symlink from `/bin/sh` to some shell: so that programs written for Bourne shell can be executed). On some unix systems, the actual Bourne shell may well be present in `/bin/sh` (note the question is not tagged 'linux'). In any case, asking for "the SH shell (not bash)" simply means that the script is to be constrained to the Bourne shell's syntax (common to sh, ash, dash, bash and others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that your regular expression is sufficiently complex to handle all types of valid URL but ignoring that, you can make it work by changing a couple of things:

```
if echo "$1" | grep -Eq "$regex"; then
                     ^  ^
```

I have enabled extended regex support using the `-E` switch and used double quotes around your variable so that it is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `grep` to :

```
grep -qP "$regex"
```

to use Perl regex and enable variable expansion (double quotation).